# How to flip the order of a TukeyHSD output?

Tags: r, output, interpretation, tukey

I'm doing a TukeyHSD to compare differences in student ratings (of resource usefulness) by year.  My output currently looks like this:

```
$year
                      diff         lwr         upr     p adj
first-fifth     0.85931811  0.38223995  1.33639626 0.0000055
```

Let's say I want to present the results comparing fifth year students to first year students (opposite of how it is currently). Would I just be able to say the difference is -0.859, with a CI of (-0.38 -- -1.34) ?

This makes sense to me logically, first years think X resource is 0.85 points more useful than fifth years, so fifth years logically think X resource is 0.85 points LESS useful (thus, presenting it as -0.85, with the negative to indicate /less/), but I wanted to see if others agree and/or if there's code that would take care if this for me.

relevant output:

```
> USEunivcourses <- aov(USEUniversitycourses~year+collegegen+genderaov+race,data=aovapril29)
> summary(USEunivcourses)
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
year          5   53.3  10.651  10.336 1.99e-09 ***
collegegen    2    6.0   3.023   2.934 0.054160 .  
genderaov     2    3.0   1.518   1.473 0.230176    
race          1   15.5  15.531  15.071 0.000118 ***
Residuals   479  493.6   1.030                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
44 observations deleted due to missingness
> TukeyHSD(USEunivcourses)
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = USEUniversitycourses ~ year + collegegen + genderaov + race, data = aovapril29)

$year
                      diff         lwr         upr     p adj
first-fifth     0.85931811  0.38223995  1.33639626 0.0000055
fourth-fifth   -0.03153453 -0.53631736  0.47324829 0.9999747
second-fifth    0.52081475  0.05229631  0.98933318 0.0193923
sixplus-fifth   0.02429150 -0.57931232  0.62789531 0.9999972
third-fifth     0.39425487 -0.09638047  0.88489021 0.1963277
fourth-first   -0.89085264 -1.32257593 -0.45912935 0.0000001
second-first   -0.33850336 -0.72720481  0.05019809 0.1285308
sixplus-first  -0.83502661 -1.37900902 -0.29104420 0.0001998
third-first    -0.46506324 -0.88015640 -0.04997008 0.0179147
second-fourth   0.55234928  0.13010415  0.97459442 0.0027872
sixplus-fourth  0.05582603 -0.51260954  0.62426160 0.9997634
third-fourth    0.42578940 -0.02086983  0.87244863 0.0717349
sixplus-second -0.49652325 -1.03301446  0.03996796 0.0879922
third-second   -0.12655988 -0.53178610  0.27866634 0.9479600
third-sixplus   0.36996337 -0.18594699  0.92587373 0.4007642

$collegegen
                diff        lwr       upr     p adj
FGEN-CGEN -0.1816192 -0.3991476 0.0359092 0.1226158
NA-CGEN    0.4500391 -0.4657542 1.3658324 0.4805846
NA-FGEN    0.6316583 -0.2826896 1.5460063 0.2364157

$genderaov
                    diff        lwr       upr     p adj
male-female -0.005014762 -0.2571716 0.2471420 0.9987955
nb-female   -0.362872061 -0.8666950 0.1409509 0.2087853
nb-male     -0.357857299 -0.8911500 0.1754354 0.2563204

$race
                     diff        lwr        upr     p adj
white-nonwhite -0.3904405 -0.5907759 -0.1901052 0.0001455
```

Comment: Could you please share some code and data using `dput`?

Comment: added the relevant code and output to the original question

Comment: You can try converting the `year` variable into a factor variable of desired order of levels before running the tests: `aovapril29$year <- factor(aovapril29$year, levels = c("first", "second", "third", ... ))`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this and I get the same output from the Tukey. While coding answers are helpful and I'll definitely try again, my question is mostly about interpretation.